# Code changes are not included to build- Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have recently moved to Mac and am developing using Visual Studio 2013 from Parallels. I have pulled a project from BitBucket repo using Sourcetree.

Now any code changes I make do not translate to any changes. For example, I can comment out all Start up routines and project works fine (just like before commenting).

In addition, all breakpoints are displayed as empty balls with an exclamation mark on them (The breakpoint will not be hit. The source code is different from the original version).

I tried cleaning, rebuilding, deleting obj / bin directories to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the remark 'The source code is different from the original version' is true.

The only hint is 'Parallels' however that should not be a problem. A few guesses:

1. Are you running a web project with ISS development host? It could run your site from another folder, however VSS will attach to this instance.
2. Do you have build output errors (See the errors tab). If so, check whether the setting 'Run last successful build' is enabled. This could disable running your unexpected binaries.
3. Is there a overridden entry point for debugging? It could be a precompiled version is included in the sources or from some other location. In this case deleting obj/bin folders won't work.

Just let's make sure this is not related to Parallels. I personally use Fusion with Unity but I expect similar tech. Is it a Bootcamp installation? In that case try to boot native and find out whether the problem still exist.

Comment: Thank you. 
1. The project is VSTO project (although part of solution is web based)
2. No errors, no "last config". Interestingly, if I intentionally make syntax mistake, the project does not build (and does not start debugging)
3. I am not sure how to check this. Can you help me?